# How to share Code Style settings between developers in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like all developers on my team to use the same default code style settings.  We all use IntelliJ 11+ as our IDE and we use git as our source control system.

What is the easiest way to make sure they're all using the same settings?  I thought there would be a way to check in the style settings into the project and have their editors discover them automatically, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

PS. I don't mind if developers consciously override some of the default settings with their own preferences, but I do want to make sure that we all at least start from a common set of default settings.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Code Style can be [copied to project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copying-code-style-settings.html) and saved in `.idea/codeStyles` to be [shared via version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839):

> **Copy to Project**   Click this button to create a copy of the current global scheme to the project level. After creating the copy, IntelliJ
>   IDEA suggests to switch to this new scheme at the project level.

Comment: Do you know what files are involved? We currently have git set to exclude files in the .idea directory, i'd like to modify our git settings to not exclude the code style files.

Comment: for me, it was .idea/projectCodeStyle.xml

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid for IntelliJ 13. I finally found my personal code style settings stored in `~/.IntelliJIdea13/config/codestyles`, which was not easy to find. But exporting them to the project did not produce any `.idea` directory in the project. It'd sure be nice if there was just a straightforward "export" or "Save As" option in the UI.

Comment: On Max OS X and IntelliJ 13, the code style file location was: `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/codestyles/`. The Library folder is usually hidden when using Finder so use CMD+SHIFT+G (or the command-line).

Comment: On Ubuntu / Intellij v2016.3.2 it is in: .idea/codeStyles/Project.xml and codeStyleConfig.xml

Comment: This answer is still relevant but the first link has changed: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-code-style.html

Comment: I think that for more recent versions of IntelliJ the styles are stored in `.idea/codeStyles` directory instead of just the mentioned file.

Answer (score 20):

The *Settings Repository* feature was introduced at *IntelliJ IDEA 2016*.

This option helps us to share IDE settings between different computers, including sharing settings between developers.

The settings are stored at Git repository, for example on GitHub or Bitbucket.

To setup Git repository we should set URL via *Settings Repository* menu option.

[image: Calling settings]

The developer can load remote settings, overwrite remote settings or merge local settings with remote ones.

[image: Set url and choose action]

The structure of Git repository with settings:

[image: Git repository structure]

I used personal access token for GitHub authentication.

---

More information:

- [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository)
- [Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)

Comment: My team found out about this feature recently. I find it difficult to use because it **shares all the settings** such as code style but also color scheme which is definitely not the same across the team. Is there a way to **configure a list of wanted settings** files while excluding others?

Comment: @JID We were facing a similar problem because we only want to share code formatting settings, and not theme settings etc. We managed to make it work by using settings repository with a .gitignore that excludes everything except the code formatter stuff.

Comment: It's not compatible with the jetbrains-account settings synchronization though :/ It would've made alot more sense if the account was simply a personal settings repository?

While I respect that it's a hard problem I find the settings sharing mechanismns for the jetbrains products rather bad and confusing..

Answer (score 14):

I came across this *long* after the fact, but thought I'd share if anyone ran into this. Add the following to your .gitignore

```html
# IDE - IntelliJ
/.idea/*
# Keep the code styles.
!/.idea/codeStyles
/.idea/codeStyles/*
!/.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml
!/.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml
# Keep the inspection levels
!/.idea/inspectionProfiles
/.idea/inspectionProfiles/*
!/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
```

And of course, make sure your .gitignore also has a ! in front of it so these changes get picked up.

Basically, gitignore's recursive looking is a little wonky, so the below ignores a directory's contents, except for a subdirectory, then ignores that subdirectory's contents, except for the files we want.

codeStyleConfig lets you use per project settings, the project file itself is your actual code styles, and I included the Project_Default as it holds the warning levels, which you likely want if you're doing the code style work anyways.

Comment: I got it working with a simpler version regarding codestyles: 

.idea/*
!.idea/codeStyles

Answer (score 4):

You can create .editorconfig file in Your project (and it can be managed on directory level). More info on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html#editorconfig and https://editorconfig.org/

With this approach You can keep all Your code style settings in one file and it's not limited to IJ only.

Comment: Well yes, but editorconfig officially supports only a very few properties. The rest exported from IDEA will have `ij_` prefix, as they are not official. Most likely these properties won't be understood by other IDEs.

Comment: I'm not sure about other IDEs, but if they support editorconfig (even with their own prefix) then You can then keep all in one file and well, some options would be duplicated.