# Add Formatter settings to Eclipse and IntelliJ projects with Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, formatting

I'd like to automatically include the formatter settings I ship in my repo (in fact the one from Google) in the project settings for both Eclipse and IntelliJ using gradle.

Maybe I can tinker with the generated XML settings, but I'm not sure how, nor do I know how either IDE stores these settings.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA part of the question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092648/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you a lot. I hope I can utilize this knowledge. Also I noticed I completely forgot to mention that I use gradle and hope to achieve it using gradle.

Comment: I don't think it can be done with Gradle.

Comment: Considering Gradle lets you run Groovy scripts it should be possible.

Comment: Once https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174087 is implemented, you may be able to customize it via Gradle, right now you can only generate IDE configuration files from Gradle using `withXML` in the build scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using http://editorconfig.org/, it covers the most common use-cases and it's portable between most editors.