# Intellij codeStyleSettings.xml vs codeStyleConfig.xml vs codeStyle.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style

I want to set code style for the project so that all the developers of the project format the code the same way. All of the team uses IntelliJ. When I add my style in the file

> /myproject/.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml

the IDE creates the file

> /myproject/.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml

with the contents

```xml
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="Default" />
  </state>
</component>
```

Will the default settings override my code style settings? Should I use the same component name in my settings file to override the default one?

In addition to those, I see a `codeStyle.xml` file in the root directory of some well-known java libraries such as https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j , is it for another IDE or does that also have an impact on formatting in IntelliJ?

By the way, I think generally code style config is confusing if not mess, there is also IDE level global settings and I think/hope it will be applied when there are no rules for a specific option, right?

Comment: You could try https://editorconfig.org/ instead which should be portable between IDEs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it maybe the route I will take but I want to learn how is my ide behaving in my case. Some teams may not decide to use editorconfig.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Intellij IDEA 2017.3 has got new project code style settings format. Now all code style settings are located under `<PROJECT_ROOT>/.idea/codeStyles` directory with the ultimate intention to support multiple project code styles linked to different scopes. New code style settings format is also cleaner and contains all code style settings properly grouped per language. Some old legacy Java, HTML settings previously stored without any language tag are moved to "JavaCodeStyleSettings", "HTMLCodeStyleSettings" etc. respectively.
- The old `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml` is imported into two new files: `.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml` containing a link to preferred project code style and `.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml` with code style settings for different languages. The latter is optional and created only if there are non-default settings. If `.idea` directory is under version control, both files can be added to VCS too. The old `codeStyleSettings.xml` is kept for backwards compatibility.

---

Original answer (now obsolete):

- `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml` stores the project specific code style that is for sharing with the project so that all the team members have the same code style applied automatically for this specific project. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092648/104891) for details.
- `.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml` is used to override the default project code style.
  By default it contains `<option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />` so that project specific configuration from `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml` is used. If you switch your code style settings to use a scheme stored in the IDE instead of the project scheme, this file will store your choice.

[image: code style]

- IntelliJ IDEA also has support for `.editorconfig` which will have the priority and override IDE and project scheme by default. [Check the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html) for more details.
- `codeStyle.xml` in the project root is for Eclipse IDE and is not used by IntelliJ IDEA. It can be probably used by IntelliJ IDEA as well, if you have [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter) plug-in installed and configured accordingly.

Comment: Thanks very much. When I change codestyle scheme I saw how the `<option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="Default" />` turned to `<option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />`

Comment: @CrazyCoder Please notice that from IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 `.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml` is **deprecated** as described in the ["New project code style settings format in 2017.3" wiki page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/New+project+code+style+settings+format+in+2017.3) (Aug 31, 2017). You might want to update your answer accordingly. - Also here is a [possible fix](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34139) for the article.

Comment: @JJD Thanks for the heads up, both are fixed now.

Comment: @CrazyCoder "containing a link to preferred project code style and" any documentation on how that link works? I can see the value it set to the name of the code_scheme I want to use, but I don't understand how it knows where to look for it