# Autoupdate Intellij IDEA code style from cloud

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

We need to have common code style config for all developers at project. How tune Intellij IDEA for auto-update code style config from cloud?
For example: Added codeStyleSettings.xml to git repository. When new changes of codeStyleSettings.xml pulled from repository, updated local config of project code style.

Comment: Check [this web help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository). Does it cover your needs?

Comment: No, Settings Repository shared all settings. I need shared only code style. I found answer there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087439/how-to-share-code-style-settings-between-developers-in-intellij (code style copied to project and save in .idea/, next just need exclude ignoring directory codeStyles in gitignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer there - [How to share Code Style settings between developers in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087439/how-to-share-code-style-settings-between-developers-in-intellij).
Code Style can be [copied to project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copying-code-style-settings.html) and saved in .idea/codeStyles. Next needs exclude ignoring this folder in gitignore.